# Getting error Expected message to contain InResponseTo "id142e8231161a4246bf345d331a7b0ace", but found none. in Kendor.AuthServices.MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, saml-2.0, kentor-authservices

This is my web.config File

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <section name="kentor.authServices" type="Kentor.AuthServices.Configuration.KentorAuthServicesSection, Kentor.AuthServices" />
    </configSections>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <trace>
            <listeners>
                <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
                    <filter type="" />
                </add>
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>
    <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />

        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/AuthServices/SignIn" />
        </authentication>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        </modules>

    </system.webServer>

    <kentor.authServices entityId="http://myapp.ci.01/metadata" returnUrl="http://localhost:63238/AuthServices/Acs">
        <identityProviders>
            <add entityId="http://myapp.ci.01/metadata" 
                 signOnUrl="https://sso.myapp.com/issue/saml/?binding=redirect" 
                allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" binding="HttpRedirect">
                <signingCertificate fileName="~/App_Data/MyApp.AuthServices.StubIdp.cer" />
            </add>
        </identityProviders>
    </kentor.authServices>
    <system.identityModel.services>
        <federationConfiguration>
            <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" name="RMInform" />
        </federationConfiguration>
    </system.identityModel.services>


    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
            <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

But while redirecting to my localhost after sign in I am getting error

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Expected message to contain InResponseTo
>   "id0dda716c55fd41bd98d4899ca3e14036", but found none.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   Kentor.AuthServices.Exceptions.Saml2ResponseFailedValidationException:
>   Expected message to contain InResponseTo
>   "id0dda716c55fd41bd98d4899ca3e14036", but found none.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [Saml2ResponseFailedValidationException: Expected message to contain
>   InResponseTo "id0dda716c55fd41bd98d4899ca3e14036", but found none.]
>   Kentor.AuthServices.Saml2P.Saml2Response.ReadAndValidateInResponseTo(XmlElement
>   xml, Saml2Id expectedInResponseTo) +295
>   Kentor.AuthServices.Saml2P.Saml2Response..ctor(XmlElement xml, Saml2Id
>   expectedInResponseTo) +317
>   Kentor.AuthServices.WebSso.AcsCommand.Run(HttpRequestData request,
>   IOptions options) +869
>   Kentor.AuthServices.Mvc.AuthServicesController.Acs() +81
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +87
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +280
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +35
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.b__41()
>   +33    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +42
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.b__33()
>   +80    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49()
>   +386    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +42
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__20()
>   +32    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +185
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +38
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.b__18(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +22    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +53
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +22    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +38
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +42
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +22    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +38
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +657    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +146

This is my SAML response

```
<saml2p:AuthnRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="idcbb43fbc52b34e88b34e71fcb80c9ac8" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2016-06-14T12:09:50Z" Destination="sso.myapp.com/issue/saml? binding=redirect" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="localhost:63238/AuthServices/Acs">; <saml2:Issuer>myapp.ci.01/metadata</saml2:Issuer>; </saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your Idp isn't properly including an `inResponseTo` attribute in the response message. This is a violation of the SAML specification.

Use a tool such as SAML Tracer for Firefox or SAML DevTools for Chrome to view the SAML messages in the browser. Check if the response has an `InResponseTo` matching the `Id` of the `AuthnRequest` sent from the SP. If it is not present, the Idp is incorrect.

It might be possible to add a compatibility setting in AuthServices to ignore this error. If you need that, please open an issue on the AuthServices GitHub issue tracker to discuss it.

Comment: <saml2p:AuthnRequest 
    xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
    xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" 
    ID="idcbb43fbc52b34e88b34e71fcb80c9ac8" 
    Version="2.0" 
    IssueInstant="2016-06-14T12:09:50Z" 
    Destination="https://sso.myapp.com/issue/saml/?
    binding=redirect" 
AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://localhost:63238/AuthServices/Acs">
    <saml2:Issuer>http://myapp.ci.01/metadata</saml2:Issuer>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>

Comment: The above is my SAML response. It doesnt have an InResponseTo attribute

Comment: Also in here: https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/blob/master/doc/Configuration.md#allowunsolicitedauthnresponse-attribute, it is given that we can disble by giving it true. In my case it is also not working

Comment: Your Idp is violating the SAML spec. The `allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse` setting is to allow responses without a prior request. It is not to allow the Idp to break the specification, but the docs could be a bit more clear about that.

Comment: Thanks @AndersAbel. I think i will talk to my Idproviders to include the inResponseTo in the saml response

Comment: @AndresAbel.. I have wrongly attached the request as response in question. In SAML response, I am clearly getting `inresponsto` attribute             `<saml:SubjectConfirmation 
                Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <saml:SubjectConfirmationData 
                    NotBefore="2016-06-15T05:41:44.18Z" 
                    NotOnOrAfter="2016-06-15T05:51:44.18Z" 
                    Recipient="http://localhost:63238/AuthServices/Acs" 
                    InResponseTo="id5bd3fdffbcb24c8c944084262cd2c05e" />
            </saml:SubjectConfirmation>`

Comment: If you're getting an InResponseTo and still get that error it might be a bug. Please join https://gitter.im/KentorIT/authservices to discuss.

Comment: That's on the `SubjectConfirmation`. There should also be an `InResponseTo` directly on the `Response`. It's that one that AuthServices looks for.

Comment: Okay once again I am checking with my idproviders